# native way to select multiple table view cells in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have a use case where I need to select multiple tableviewcells in a uitableview. After I select the cells I will use the results of the selection for processing.

How do I accomplish this the standard `iOS/UIKit` way?  What controls will I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "What controls will I use"?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for UITableView?

Comment: @Atma, have a look at the answer in this post, or as rmaddy said take a look at the docs. Here is the link man http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176907/uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark-multiple-selection-detect-which-cells-selected

Comment: Not sure what the fuss is about. This seems to be a situation that many apps need and I wanted to know the cocoa approach to it.  I think the community was robbed of some valuable information by putting this on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For handling such scenarios you need an additional array for keeping the selected items.

And in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you need to push/pop the selected item based on it's current state (selected/deselected)

The implementation looks like:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
           [selectedItemsArray addObject:[yourDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       }
       else
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
           [selectedItemsArray removeObject:[yourDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       }
       [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
```

Also you need to modify the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like:

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       NSString *cellIdent = @"cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];
       if(cell == nil)
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdent];
       //Adding items to cell
       if([selectedItemsArray containsObject:[yourDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
       }
       else
       {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       }
       return cell;
    }
```

Instead of displaying native `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` you can use custom images for the selected state. You can refer this tutorial for [custom accessory-view](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/).

Comment: Why using another array? Just add a flag to your model that gets set once the user has selected the corresponding row.

Comment: @Till: Yeah, that is also a wonderful solution. I used the array for easily managing the selected items. If user need to do something with all selected object. In array it's easy. If the change is in model object. You need to find all selected object first then modify it. But I didn't think of that, a wonderful idea. Thanks for sharing !!!